# python utf-8 problem

Tags: python, utf-8, persian

this is my script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

res = urllib2.urlopen('http://tazeh.net')
html = res.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html))

title = soup.findAll('title')
print title
```

when im am running this script in terminal i get wronged text like that

```
$ python test.py

[<title>ŮžŘ§Ű&OElig;ÚŻŘ§Ů&Dagger; ŘŽŘ¨ŘąŰ&OElig; ŘŞŘ­Ů&bdquo;Ű&OElig;Ů&bdquo;Ű&OElig; ŘŞŘ§Ř˛Ů&Dagger;</title>]
```

this title in utf-8 encoding and persian language

i'm newer in python what's wrong?

Comment: have you tried title.decode()?

Comment: change bottom of script to `code` title = soup.findAll('title')
title = title[0].string.decode('utf-8')
print title `code` got error return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Efazati this is not your business :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i add (like one of the comments suggested doing in less useful place):

```
html = html[:10000].decode("utf-8")
```

(the slice is because decode failed at an offset further into the page)

before:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

it prints:

```
[<title>پایگاه خبری تحلیلی تازه</title>]
```

Comment: the slice [:10000] is because decode failed at an offset further into the page.

Answer (score 1):

`''.join(html)` is needless.  The variable `html` is already a single string.

However, it appears that the page was not properly encoded in UTF-8.